# WPF Custom Control Design question

Tags: wpf, controls

I have a design question:

If you had to make a WPF Combobox with search support,
(= combobox that shows a popup with some Buttons, Search TextBox, List.. etc
the selected item feed to the default's ComboBox TextBox.)
What would you do?

1. Write a custom control (diretly inheriting from `System.Windows.Control`)
2. Write a custom control inheritnig from `Selector` / `ComboBox`
3. Make a `UserControl`
4. Use a default ComboBox with a 'special Template' (`CotnrolTemplate`/`Style` ?) extended to search functionality
5. Use a default ComboBox with style and attached `EventHandlers`..

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that, and the method i used was option 2 - i did a template control inheriting from a third party combo, and replaced the popup contents with my own template.